# How to execute AWS SSM send command to run shell script with arguments from Lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-ssm

Currently working on a AWS Lambda function to execute shell script (with arguments) remotely on EC2 instance.

Shell script argument values are stored as environment variables in Lambda.

How to reference the env variables of Lambda inside SSM send command?

Have a code snippet like this: (but it doesn't work)

```
   response = ssm_client.send_command(
        InstanceIds=instances,
        DocumentName="AWS-RunShellScript",
        Parameters={
            "commands": ["sh /bin/TEST/test.sh -v {{os.environ:tar_version}}"]
        },
        OutputS3BucketName="tar",
        OutputS3Region="eu-west-1"
    )
```

Request you to please help me here.

Thanks

Comment: yes that's correct Paolo. Please help

Comment: In Python, use `os.environ['MY_ENV_VAR']` after importing the `os` module. Include that value directly in your `Parameters`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need to do is simple string formatting. Using Python's f-strings:

```
import os

tar_version = os.environ['TAR_VERSION']

response = ssm_client.send_command(
        InstanceIds=instances,
        DocumentName="AWS-RunShellScript",
        Parameters={
            "commands": [f"sh /bin/TEST/test.sh -v {tar_version}"]
        },
        OutputS3BucketName="tar",
        OutputS3Region="eu-west-1"
    )
```