# Pass local variable value in AWS SSM Send Command

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-ssm

I am working on an automation of Certificates on AWS EC2 and the Certificates are dumped on the EC2 using SSM. The script is written in Python, which creates a SSM session and executes the commmand to dump the Certificate.

The base64 Certificate is in a python variable (let's say "Cert" variable). How do i pass the value of this variable in the AWS SSM Send command function of boto3 ?

code:

```
Cert="-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----........."

    response = ssm_client.send_command(
        InstanceIds=[
            healthy_instance[0] 
            ],
                 DocumentName="AWS-RunShellScript",
                 Parameters={
                     'commands':[
                         '**Command to be added here**'
                         ]
                     },
        )
```

Comment: You can format a string with `f"some command text {Cert} more optional text"`

Comment: @JacobIRR Not sure if I fully understood your suggestion. Could you please elaborate a bit more ?

Comment: If your desired command was `make_cert_do_something you_cert -some-option=1` you could inject the cert string into the command using my code above.

Comment: Great! I made an answer so you can accept.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to execute AWS SSM send command to run shell script with arguments from Lambda?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71893560/how-to-execute-aws-ssm-send-command-to-run-shell-script-with-arguments-from-lamb)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can format a string with `f"some command text {Cert} more optional text"`–